# strongly typed wmi getting subfolders

Tags: wmi

I need to create a treeview of a remote filesystem. To do this I am using WMI and mgmtclassgen.exe

using Win32_LogicalDisk I get my drive letters.

Now when user wants to browse its subfolders I want to get the subfolders, i am able to get that using

```
ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", @"Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='e:\'} Where AssocClass =Win32_Subdirectory ResultRole = PartComponent")
```

but this is not strongly typed. How can i use the strongly typed classes of Win32_Directory and Win32_Subdirectory to get subfolders?

Comment: Why do you need `strongly typed`?

Comment: Because it is cleaner that way, plus intellisense will let me know all the available properties

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't any .NET implementation of wmi, so no strongly typing as of yet.

(I am currently working on a .net implementation though).